# Loading dwg and dxf in autocad

Tags: qgis, postgis, autocad

We have a dwg file.  When we open it in autocad it looks ok. When we convert it to dxf and load it in either postgis or qgis it is located about 1000 miles from where its suppose to be.  If we reload the dxf file into autocad it is located correctly. We're using the same cordinate system (fl84) in qgis that autocad is using but we are apparently missing something.

I am verifying the data in autocad by loading a basemap and its appearing in the location I expect it to be

Why does autocad know the coordinate system but its missing from my dxf file but qgis does not?

Comment: How are you verifying the correctness of your data in Autocad? My first guess would be that Autocad / your data is at fault. Compare the coordinates in QGIS and Autocad. P.S.: Please try to elaborate your Question. At the moment your aren't even asking an actual question...

Comment: AutoCAD uses modelspace and scaling GIS does not. I would take two points in my CAD drawing find the corresponding points in the GIS, grab the GIS point coordinates and use the align command in CAD. Then try to bring the DXF into GIS.

Comment: What EPSG code or proj definition is `fl84`? What units have your Autocad drawings, meter or mm?